# /page1/ and /page2/ shows the same - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm a newbie to express, and I have my app which looks like this:

[image: none]

I have my code like this:

```
    const express = require("express"),
            app = express(),
            server = require("http").Server(app),
            io = require("socket.io")(server)

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/sign-in/public"))
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/log-in/public"))

app.get("/sign-in", (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "/sign-in/public/index.html"))
app.get("/log-in", (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + "/log-in/public/index.html"))

server.listen(8081, () => console.log(`Listening on ${server.address().port}`))
```

But the problem is, after have executed `node server.js`, when I go to `localhost:8081/log-in`, I'll see the `sign-up` page, same with `localhost:8081` and `localhost:8081/sign-up`. But, I wanna have the `log-in` page when I go to `localhost:8081/log-in`... How can I achieve that? What did I do wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are serving both static path under the same path. Your code should look like this:

```js
const express = require("express"),
app = express();

app.use('/sign-in/', express.static(__dirname + "/sign-in/public"));
app.use('/log-in/', express.static(__dirname + "/log-in/public"));

app.listen(8081, () => console.log(`Listening on 8081`));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work fine

```
app.get('/login', function(req,res){
 res.sendfile(__dirname + 'login/public/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Post the screen shot of your login directory foler

Comment: It should be `res.sendFile`, not `res.sendfile`. Note that functions are case-sensitive in most programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Then the reason you are getting this error is because You have defined one Static file route you cannot define it Again this might be the problem i think so i worked 6 months on Mean Stack